# liveness and readiness probe for multiple containers in a pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

I would like to know if there is a possibility to apply liveness and readiness probe check to multiples containers in a pod or just for one container in a pod.
I did try checking with multiple containers but the probe check fails for container A and passes for container B in a pod.

Comment: please provide a YAML example of what you're trying so that the community can be more helpful in understanding the problem and suggesting a solution :)

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to the community.

**Answer**

It's absolutely possible to apply multiple probes for containers within the pod. What happens next depends on a probe.

There are three probes listed in [Containers probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes) which can be used: `liveness`, `readiness` and `startup`. I'll describe more about `liveness` and `readiness`:

**Liveness**

> `livenessProbe`: Indicates whether the container is running. If the
> `liveness` probe fails, the kubelet kills the container, and the
> container is subjected to its restart policy. If a Container does not
> provide a `liveness` probe, the default state is Success

> The kubelet uses liveness probes to know when to restart a container.
> For example, liveness probes could catch a deadlock, where an
> application is running, but unable to make progress. Restarting a
> container in such a state can help to make the application more
> available despite bugs.

In case of `livenessProbe` fails, `kubelet` will restart the container in POD, the POD will remain the same (its age as well).

Also it can be checked in `container events`, this quote is from `Kubernetes in Action - Marko Lukša`

> I’ve seen this on many occasions and users were confused why their
> container was being restarted. But if they’d used `kubectl describe`,
> they’d have seen that the container terminated with exit code 137 or
> 143, telling them that the pod was terminated externally

**Readiness**

> `readinessProbe`: Indicates whether the container is ready to respond to
> requests. If the `readiness` probe fails, the endpoints controller
> removes the Pod's IP address from the endpoints of all Services that
> match the Pod. The default state of `readiness` before the initial delay
> is Failure. If a Container does not provide a `readiness` probe, the
> default state is Success

> The kubelet uses readiness probes to know when a container is ready to
> start accepting traffic. A Pod is considered ready when all of its
> containers are ready. One use of this signal is to control which Pods
> are used as backends for Services. When a Pod is not ready, it is
> removed from Service load balancers.

What happens here is kubernetes checks if webserver in container is serving requests and if not, `readinessProbe` fails and POD's IP (generally speaking entire POD) will be removed from endpoints and no traffic will be directed to the POD.

**Useful links**

- [Container probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes) - general information and `types`
- [Configure Liveness, Readiness and Startup Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) (practice and examples)

Answer (score 0):

As per K8S spec, liveness and readiness check can be executed for every container and carries its own template, which is nested into the specific container. See for example : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/main/content/en/examples/pods/probe/exec-liveness.yaml .

So I think it really depends on what are you checking for in the probe and how container *A* could answer in a different fashion than container *B*.

If you have a need for templating, you should look into [kustomize](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/guides/introduction/kustomize/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, I have tried this. Here's what I tried.

- One deployment with 2 replica.
- Each replica pod with 4 containers.
- Each container with it's own liveness probe.
- Liveness probe used `http-get` to check container application health.

**Few things to take care:**

- Since `<PODIP>:<CONTAINERPORT>/<ENDPOINT>` is used by liveness probe to make http request, one must make sure `<CONTAINERPORT>` is different for each container. Else the pod will go to `CrashLoopBack`.

Example:

```yaml
containers:
       - name: container1
...
        args:
        - --leader-election=true
        - --http-endpoint=:8080
...
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http-endpoint
          protocol: TCP
...
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 1
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz/leader-election
            port: http-endpoint
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 20
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 10
...
       - name: container2
...
        args:
        - --leader-election=true
        - --http-endpoint=:8081
...
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
          name: http-endpoint
          protocol: TCP
...
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 1
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz/leader-election
            port: http-endpoint
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 20
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 10
...
```

**Suggestion:**

If each container is a separate application and do no depend on each other and is important enough that you need a liveness probe for it then, it should be better to deploy them in separate pods.